# Implementing Merge Join in Python

Tags: python, sql, database, join

I am familiar with JOIN operations in SQL, but I don't really understand how they work internally.

I was given a task of implementing a merge_join function in Python. I already implemented a nested loop join correctly:

```
def nested_loop_join(self, outer, outer_join_index, inner, inner_join_index):
    inner_list = list(inner)
    for outer_row in outer:
        for inner_row in inner_list:
            if outer_row[outer_join_index] == inner_row[inner_join_index]:
                yield outer_row + inner_row
```

My merge join is:

```
def merge_join(self, outer, outer_join_index, inner, inner_join_index):
    inner_list = list(inner)
    for outer_row in outer:
        for inner_row in inner_list:
            if outer_row[outer_join_index]==inner_row[inner_join_index]:
                yield outer_row+inner_row
            else:
                yield outer_row
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.
From what I understand shouldn't merge join be just like attaching the inner table to the outer? What did I do wrong here?

Comment: for people who want to use such an algorithm as opposed to write it, have a look at [Pandas df.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are referring to the *algorithm* called merge join and not the SQL command called `merge` (the latter does both inserts and updates).

The merge join algorithm takes two sorted lists of records.  When the keys are the same, it produces the Cartesian product of the values with the two records.  If either input has key values not in the other, then that key is not in the output.

I'm not going to write the Python code that does this.  However, if you understand what the algorithm does, it should be pretty simple to convert to Python.